# Can't login to AdMob

Tags: google-account, google-adsense, google-admob

When I try to login into Google's AdMob I get following error:

> You do not have access to the AdSense account that is connected to
> your AdMob account. Learn more

Now from what I've found it all targets not having AdSense or Google Ads account, however I do have a Google AdSense and Google Ads accounts under the same `@gmail.com` account and I can successfully login to both (I can see admin dashboard in both).

I would also like to note, that I am the one and only *admin* on both of these accounts.

Google support is linking users to this page https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356424?hl=en however there is only a variation of this error and is implying some sort of account cancelations - which is obviously not the case since I can access both of the admin dashboards.

Is there some user setting I'm missing? Some special way how/where to setup/add the AdMobs account?

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to log in using different credentials. Try to log in with the credentials that you already used to create an Adsense account. Read more details from this google: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/O3fC4vP-a1o?pli=1

Are you still having other problems while using AdMob. You can switch to other AdMob alternatives such as AdPumb and Appodeal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).